# Dotnet ef Migrations error - Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSourceDependencies'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm getting the following error when I run the following command.
`dotnet ef migrations add init`

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.1 initialized 'DataContext' using provider 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore:6.0.1+MySQL8.0.29' with options: None
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSourceDependencies' while attempting to activate 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLTypeMappingSource'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite(ResultCache lifetime, Type serviceType, Type implementationType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact(ServiceDescriptor descriptor, Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain, Int32 slot)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite(Type serviceType, CallSiteChain callSiteChain)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(Type serviceType)
   at 
.
.
.
.
System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.TypeMappingSourceDependencies' while attempting to activate 'MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLTypeMappingSource'.
```

My project file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

program.cs class

```
global using SuperHero.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseMySQL("server=localhost;port=3306;database=superherodb;user=root;password=root");
});




// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Data context class

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace SuperHero.Data
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }


        public DbSet<Models.SuperHero> SuperHeroes {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Here is my Model class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SuperHero.Models
{
    public class SuperHero
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        public string LastName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
        public string Place { get; set; } = String.Empty;

    }
}
```

I checked the MySQL documentation. But I think its a bit outdated. Any help is much appriciated

Comment: I think you also need an override like so

`protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) { }`

Take a look at the documentatiion for this.

Comment: I tried with that but still getting the same error. I'm using MySQL server 5.7. Do I have to mention that somewhere?